# Machine learning - PCA and KNN on rgb images is too slow (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca, knn

I work with python and images of tables (taken from above). My aim is to take a photo of a random table and then find the most similar tables to it in my database. Obviously, the main feature which distinguishes the tables are their shape (square, rectangular, round, oval) but there are also other details.

For now, I am just running a PCA and a KNN on rgb images of tables to find the most similar tables in the database for each of the tables of the database. My source code is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from glob import glob
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn import preprocessing


data = []

# Read images from file
for filename in glob('Tables/*.jpg'):

    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    img = np.array(img)

    # Check that all my images are of the same resolution
    if height == 529 and width == 940:

        # Reshape each image so that it is stored in one line
        img = np.concatenate(img, axis=0)
        img = np.concatenate(img, axis=0)
        data.append(img)

# Normalise data
data = np.array(data)
Norm = preprocessing.Normalizer()
Norm.fit(data)
data = Norm.transform(data)

# PCA model
pca = PCA(0.95)
pca.fit(data)
data = pca.transform(data)

# K-Nearest neighbours
knn = neighbors.NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='minkowski').fit(data)
distances, indices = knn.kneighbors(data)

print(indices)
```

The problem is that when I increase the number of rgb images of tables from 400 to 460 the processing time significantly increases. Specifically, in the former case it may take around 15 minutes to retrieve the results but in the latter case even after 30 minutes the program does not return any results but it is still in processing mode.

My final goal is to run this program with 2000 or even 4000 table images but I cannot see how this can be completed with my laptop.

Am I doing anything wrong in my source code or is it simply that my mac laptop is not adequate for this task?

Comment: PCA complexity is [cubic](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/CS-498-DAF-PS/Lecture%209%20-%20PCA.pdf). So your problem is at least constrained algorithmically (it does not scale well).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I had this in mind but even without the PCA the program did not finish for 460 images within 30 minutes.

Comment: KNN also scales bad for high-dimensions. Look up KD-trees (or Ball-trees). To be honest: i think all image-search approaches scale-down those images before doing anything. E.g. 100x100. Also: many approaches just do grayscale.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I thought about cropping the images or taking images of lower resolution or/and taking grayscale images. But then I  lose pretty valuable information. So I am not sure that this is the best idea. (Also I wonder if I can even run a simple neural network in my laptop as this requires lots of images)

Comment: So @sascha, if you think that PCA or/and KNN are too resources-consuming then what else do you suggest for my task? (Obviously I know other more advanced machine learning algorithms and I thought that these two would be the less resources/time-consuming for my machine)

Comment: No cropping, not taking lower-res images. Resizing (and maybe grayscale). Let me assure you: every large-scale web-image search will downscale/resize images (some info lost; but we need that to scale). That's also done in face-recognition! What i recommend? Look for academic papers about the topic (image-search, similarity-search, perceptual-hashing, learning-to-hash). There is a lot of work done and many many different approaches are available.

Comment: Ok, I got it but I do not really understand what is the difference between resizing an image of 1000x2000 to 500x1000 than just simply taking the same image available on internet in resolution 500x1000. I think that these two are identical.

Comment: They are not necessarily identical (there is more than one resize algorithm). But i thought about the use-case. If i would implement an image-hosting service i would not tell my customers: only 500x1000 images are allowed. But still i need to downscale internally to check for dupes. So i will need to resize.

Comment: Plus,  I did not really expect that even simply to run the most basic machine learning algorithms for relatively few data (in comparison with big data) would require to study any research papers!

Comment: Yes, obviously in this sense resizing is useful

Comment: It depends on your goal. While PCA and co. can work, they are typically less good than other approaches described in academics. There is also more than one mthod to tackle PCA. Approximations could probably be done in less than cubic time. But that's stuff you have to research if you keep the PCA-pipeline. In general: checking out complexity of PCA / KNN is more or less the first step when observing scaling problems (and it tells you it's a problem of the chosen approach, not necessarily the implementation).

Comment: Also reading papers can improve your approach too. I was struggling to do this kind of thing to videos in the past (non slowly) until i just recognized, that most papers do not even do the whole image-hash thing on all frames, but skip some (take every n-th). This is simple. But reading that immediately told me: well   seems this could work.

Comment: Personally, what I am really getting from our discussion is that I must simply enhance my hardware to run these things than investing so much time in reading research papers for so elementary tasks. (I love reading research papers but I think that it is secondary for these simple tasks)

Comment: No No No! What you should learn is: asymptotic complexity beats hardware **and** algorithmics / software beats hardware ! This is basic computer-science! Hardware-upgrades can be valuable with O(n) O(nlogn), maybe O(n^2) algorithms. But well... PCA is already O(n^3) (yeah, i arbitrarily draw sone line). Buying new HW is a waste. In terms of algorithmics, i bet you would not use insertion-sort on 1M elements, when MergeSort is available (yes, one is more complex than the other).

Comment: Haha, I think that you are overreacting. Obviously, I know this about computation complexity but for relatively small datasets HW upgrade can be useful in the very short-term (for business purposes) than investing so much time in reading research papers.

Comment: I just realized, that you are trying to match objects in the first place. This is even more hard to image-similarity-search and your first approach of just using this approach will also fail (on mostly all scenarios; e.g. relative-positioning different; shadows...). But ok... some things are hard and there is a reason there is academics (PCA was academics-only at some time in the past too).

Comment: Have you timed you code? It could well be that your glob loop is very slow. Could you run it on its own (without the classification part) and see how long it takes.

Comment: Thanks @KRKirov for your response. I put a print command after the glob loop and I show that the program finishes the loop within a minute. So the problem is after this....

Comment: Yes, in a sense this what I am doing @sascha. Do you mean that it is better to get grayscale images or binary images or contours etc of the table images and try to match these?

Comment: What does mean 'most similar tables'? What is a criterion of similarity?